# Order Statistics interval sizes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions, order-statistics

Suppose an i.i.d. sample of size $n \geq 2$ drawn from a known distribution with density $g$. Let us note the associated order statistics as $(X_{(1)}, \ldots ,X_{(n)})$. I am interested in the number of $i$'s such that 
$$
X_{(i)} - X_{(i-1)} > L
$$
that is, how many backward-intervals have length at least $L$.

I tried to calculate the characteristic function of the random variable
$$
\sum_{i=2}^N \mathbb{1}\lbrace X_{(i)} - X_{(i-1)} > L\rbrace
$$

with the aid of the density of the order statistics
$$
n! \, \mathbb{1}\lbrace x_1 \leq \ldots \leq x_n \rbrace \, g(x_1) \cdots g(x_n)
$$
but to no avail (it becomes very tricky). 
Any ideas on this? Can the characteristic function be obtained explicitly in terms of $g$ and $L$?

Thanks in advance

PS: I am aware that the distribution of the range of size 1 is well known. However, I am studying an event that depends of all ranges of size 1 simultaneously.

Comment: The cases $(X_k)$ i.i.d. exponential and $(X_k)$ i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$ are probably worth looking at. In the uniform case, if $L\lt1/(n-1)$, it seems $P(S=0)=(1-(n-1)L)^n$.